# Excel to Multiple Tables in One Database Output - PDI

Tags: mysql, excel, integration, pentaho

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration for my ETL process...
I have multiple excel files that I need to merge and upload in one database. However, I cannot Distribute the fields into its corresponding tables in the database. I can only send it to one table at a time. Is there any other way to do this? How can I have multiple target table?

P.S. I'm using MySQL Workbench for the database.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using filter rows steps to direct the rows to the correct Table Output (one per destination table)?

Comment: hi, I don't need to filter it. I just need to put some columns to another table and some columns to another table again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect multiple Table output steps to your last processing step and set it to **copy** all rows to both or all target steps. Connect Table outputs (or Insert/update, etc) like in the image, then right-click the step where the stream splits and select **Copy Data to Next Steps**. In the Table outputs you obviously only specify the columns that apply to that table.

[image]